# Put this menu at top left conner HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I want the vertical menu completely at the top-left corner but right now there still about 2px top and left margin and I can not figure out why, all margin set to 0 already. Some one have any idea?

Thank so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body tag has a margin set on it, try:

```
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Comment: selected as this is the FASTEST one. All others answer are also correct and very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `margin: 0` on the `body` (live editing via Developer Tools solves it for me).

And learn to use Developer Tools ;)

Using Chrome, it showed me you had something like this:

```
body {
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

from the user agent stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks! Very good advise. I don't have reputation to reward you now but I really appreciated it. will add it when I have reputations.

Answer (score 1):

add `margin: 0px;` to your pages body tag.

Comment: holy smokes in one swoop 5 answers before I could get mine posted.. well at least I tried :P

Comment: Thanks! Very good advise. I don't have reputation to reward you now but I really appreciated it. will add it when I have reputations.

Answer (score 0):

You used some CSS Reset? If not, use this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/. Or if you want a quicker solution, use `body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that there are still default margins on the page.  Try using a [CSS reset file](http://www.cssreset.com/).  This will make sure that the margin and padding are all 0 when you start (along with some other nice resets).